# When app switcher appears execute a command Xcode swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I was wondering if anyone knew how to execute a command when the user double presses the home button and/or when the just press it to go to the home screen. Snapchat does this as it blurs out the background when double tapped or dismisses a view controller if you go out and back in.

Using Xcode 7.3.1 and if possible could the code be Swift 2.2 or 2.3

Thanks
Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Appdelegate.swift` file you will find two methods that allow you to execute code when your app changes from the foreground state to the background - like pressing the home button.

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. 
    //This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}
```

Comment: What's the current place and code in Xcode 15 with swift UI?

Answer (score 0):

plz use your AppDelegate methods

```
  func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }
```